# Error starting Ubuntu in WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 daily for the past one year. Yesterday I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` in the Ubuntu distro. After a reboot on my Windows 10 machine, I can't launch the Ubuntu distro anymore. I am getting `The Windows Subsystem for Linux instance has terminated. process exited with code 4294967295` in my Windows Terminal.

My Windows version is Windows 10 2004

Is there any ways to fix it or get files out from Ubuntu distro?

My bottomline is to save any working files inside the Ubuntu distro.

Comment: Any luck reviewing results of "code 4294967295" in your favorite search engine? It appears to be an error on the Windows side of things. Is your Windows system up-to-date?

Comment: What happens if you just run `wsl` from PowerShell?  I'm assuming it's still going to fail, but it *might* give a different/more informative error.  Also, is there any information in the Windows Event Viewer?  One Github issue I'm seeing seems to have a large number of comments mentioning a problem where an existing service was listening on port 53 (DNS).  Is there any VPN software installed or anything that might be intercepting port 53?  Acrylic DNS Proxy seems to be a common culprit.

Comment: @Nmath yes, but none of the solutions like disable and enable WSL, reset winsock etc work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve it by removing NAS storage entry in `/etc/fstab`. Ubuntu in WSL2 will fail to start if the connection to NAS storage fail.

Found the solution in this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5110#issuecomment-621149721).

Answer (score 17):

I shutdown the wsl and restarted. That did it for me.

To Shutdown:

- `wsl --shutdown`

To Start:

- Just started the Ubuntu app